# How to keep the data with values greater than 1?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have following data:

```
    Reporter ISO       AFG       AGO       ALB       ARE        ARG        ARM        AUS       AUT       AZE       BEL       BFA       BGD       BGR       BHR       BIH       BLR       BOL        BRA       BWA       CAN       CHE       CHL       CHN       CIV       CMR       COD       COG       COL       CRI       CUB       CYP       CZE       DEU        DNK       DOM       DZA       ECU        EGY       ESP       EST        ETH       FIN       FRA  GAB       GBR        GEO           GHA       GIN  GNQ       GRC       GTM       HKG       HND        HRV       HTI       HUN       IDN       IND        IRL        IRN       IRQ           ISR       ITA       JAM         JOR           JPN       KAZ        KEN       KGZ        KHM       KOR       KWT        LAO        LBN  LBR       LBY       LKA       LSO       LTU       LVA       MAR       MDA       MDG       MEX       MKD       MLI        MMR       MNG       MOZ       MRT         MUS       MYS        NAM       NER       NGA        NIC  \
    SITC                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    0011          0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.004613   0.033138   3.359434   8.726847  1.191898  0.002008  0.728046  0.437901  0.000000  1.799574  0.000000  0.421612  0.340513  0.000000   3.297533  2.755377  4.662559  0.002025  0.012436  0.050989  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  2.985603  0.058683  0.000000  0.005523  2.243466  0.481428   1.750662  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0.136531  2.034463  2.978088   0.361915  0.010336  6.421094  0.0  0.011530  11.906661  6.940706e-04  0.000000  0.0  0.020897  0.000583  0.000000  0.005827   5.801019  0.000000  2.783294  0.000000  0.056718   1.497509   0.002035  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.034540  0.000000    0.000000  1.146623e-05  2.983633   0.328246  0.738821   0.000000  0.000000  0.005245  75.826263   2.077911  0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.173766  2.974509  5.519316  0.000000  6.844561  0.000000  2.154048  0.594069  0.000000  26.490391  0.000000  0.000174  0.000000    0.000000  0.004466  34.975037  0.003507  0.000007   2.099508   
    0012          1.375525  0.000000  0.133913  0.084067   0.006681  16.383479   4.062770  0.201646  0.003303  0.011301  0.919492  0.000000  1.473571  0.000000  0.000000  0.010076  0.000000   0.000017  0.021425  0.021679  0.000147  0.030245  0.003140  0.000000  0.000362  0.000000  0.000000  0.000167  0.006618  0.000000  0.399117  0.075002  0.014116   0.007865  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0.061023  5.865379  0.549569   1.101432  0.000746  0.768423  0.0  0.714328  41.018233  1.013471e-03  0.000000  0.0  0.545327  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0.673710  0.000000  5.297044  0.015160  0.584192   0.072973  16.858856  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000389  0.000000  191.328757  0.000000e+00  5.018329   0.011129  2.938414   0.000000  0.000000  1.265317   1.255584  31.576510  0.0  0.000000  0.000000  4.233523  0.097645  0.119054  0.000000  2.542809  0.006852  0.001415  0.000000  0.000000   0.895853  0.000000  0.001034  0.000000    0.000000  0.000597  59.614346  0.111905  0.000000   0.004668   
    0013          0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0.002183   0.000000   0.000000  0.118824  0.000000  1.891616  0.000000  0.000000  0.166649  0.000000  0.434766  0.000000  0.000000   0.122091  0.000000  3.206870  0.002316  0.000000  0.667829  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.024970  0.198896  0.000000  0.004364  1.446706  0.571243  45.310792  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000  2.285895  0.343793   0.000000  0.189181  0.984170  0.0  0.007111   0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.0  1.500368  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  11.634354  0.000000  2.297556  1.535006  0.000242   1.827070   0.000000  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.001336  0.000000    0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000   0.008365  0.000000   0.012099  0.000000  0.000000   0.050146   0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  2.107540  4.406836  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0.027162  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000    0.000000  0.204559   0.000000  0.001059  0.000000   0.000000   
    0014          0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.015802   0.104162   0.000000   0.177206  1.673901  0.000000  2.213890  0.000000  0.000000  1.884009  0.002777  0.698578  0.256640  0.000000   2.192021  0.000053  0.693865  0.013870  0.000000  0.003156  0.000738  0.000000  0.001240  0.098058  0.311633  3.117316  0.000000  0.002897  2.372971  2.589253   5.315211  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0.008489  1.197066  0.067713   0.000000  0.238736  2.808734  0.0  2.362742   3.864489  1.944358e-03  0.000081  0.0  0.819977  0.855736  0.000005  0.419152   2.823619  0.000000  6.604809  0.011153  0.009950   0.259364   0.099504  0.000090  0.000000e+00  0.105376  0.078613    1.520528  8.424726e-07  0.053117   0.096929  0.088181   0.000000  0.001169  0.000311   1.712818   0.010306  0.0  0.000000  0.001087  0.004644  0.688807  0.541286  0.006068  0.000000  0.058922  0.000000  0.034544  0.040636   0.057898  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000    1.447492  3.829856   0.000223  0.011361  0.000636   0.000000   
    0015          0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.445323   2.195289   0.000000   2.307454  0.028947  0.026562  1.560077  0.002505  0.000008  0.211124  0.166718  0.003793  0.081355  0.000000   0.286775  0.000936  0.962403  0.279596  0.509734  0.000336  0.000000  0.000000  0.000124  0.000000  0.077661  0.110068  0.000000  0.009396  0.015761  0.912955   1.231179  0.027379  0.000000  0.007512   0.011966  0.231880  0.061287   0.000000  0.019807  2.278230  0.0  6.008955   0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.0  0.003849  0.013636  6.383234  0.026093   0.512240  0.000000  0.090692  0.000028  0.003678  10.118232   0.002744  0.000000  5.552301e-03  0.052228  0.464133    0.076198  1.859848e-01  0.077715   0.009641  4.554831   0.000000  0.041567  0.030370   0.000706   0.050001  0.0  0.000000  0.001080  0.016164  0.098448  0.330189  0.035837  0.000000  0.000000  0.045076  0.002459  0.000000   0.000000  0.204988  0.000000  0.000000    0.323190  0.017127   0.118358  1.816213  0.000000   0.061127   
    0019          2.404198  0.391568  4.746603  0.936277   0.472483   0.029448   0.197240  0.184044  0.015951  4.052927  0.000028  0.000000  0.039448  0.696807  0.055031  0.278160  0.003875   0.039235  0.142762  1.905431  0.122174  0.426857  0.350115  0.002159  1.978486  0.490255  0.013705  0.773129  0.114343  0.578595  0.931443  1.205081  0.423272   4.725125  0.068519  0.006181  1.301403  24.162001  1.983499  0.085567   0.205218  0.010852  2.269924  0.0  1.177672   0.059922  4.544931e-01  0.321237  0.0  0.302619  0.026811  0.127578  0.008496   0.028143  0.566884  1.295090  0.458030  0.008520   0.141866   0.483547  0.000115  4.447335e+00  0.486243  0.215677    1.878902  3.570814e-01  0.547522  25.609184  1.088240  31.133218  0.071370  1.603031   0.557699   2.015355  0.0  0.013534  0.018164  0.000000  0.837837  0.472243  6.385796  0.143335  2.607711  0.253619  0.530978  3.819587   0.007063  1.876078  0.061506  0.003411  178.476453  0.162198   4.326213  0.699293  0.007034   1.278230   
    0111          0.000000  0.000000  0.079421  0.017039   8.901930   0.016561   6.866686  1.690299  0.002603  1.098923  0.000039  0.000431  0.011489  0.000469  0.079557  7.099912  0.266318   3.096303  4.389923  3.143088  0.000200  0.069349  0.000057  0.004926  0.000137  0.000000  0.000000  0.407158  0.751635  0.000000  0.010285  0.217308  0.600825   1.897867  0.006995  0.000000  0.000000   0.022382  1.547584  0.294325   5.218987  0.299988  1.380903  0.0  0.816653   0.024922  4.210469e-07  0.001651  0.0  0.043783  0.000253  0.018290  0.883637   1.489829  0.000000  0.225030  0.000000  0.117034   8.112654   0.039480  0.000779  2.220238e-05  0.599626  0.000475    0.012492  1.381745e-01  0.105032   0.535493  0.002049   0.000000  0.003681  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000387  1.866342  1.449632  0.000032  0.173435  0.000000  1.972488  0.000000  0.000000   0.004182  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000    0.000000  0.001961   2.985457  0.004949  0.000049  34.018866   
    0112          0.027311  0.002101  0.000000  0.803547  23.202077   0.004398  10.508959  0.519682  0.001062  0.073772  0.000000  0.000079  0.018364  0.003869  0.008124  4.198086  0.407166  16.772364  4.115303  0.606431  0.001592  0.717869  0.000413  0.001026  0.000165  0.000000  0.001540  0.745339  5.223481  0.000000  0.007199  0.025556  0.136980   0.196708  0.163228  0.001689  0.000194   0.005037  0.336007  0.083353   0.001620  0.047842  0.075827  0.0  0.151379   0.551067  1.252943e-05  0.000000  0.0  0.019852  0.497362  0.352512  1.498862   0.232900  0.000000  0.065593  0.000016  6.389757   1.316056   0.003152  0.000508  0.000000e+00  0.197412  0.005625    0.847232  1.302507e-01  0.171425   0.673704  0.000031   0.000000  0.000458  0.020664   0.351126   0.005583  0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.791597  0.202655  0.004815  0.478381  0.000000  0.227916  0.004645  0.000014   0.013300  0.016229  0.000000  0.000000    0.021640  0.006599   3.261191  0.000000  0.000355  37.088510   
    0121          0.001582  0.000000  0.000000  0.052209   0.206769   7.540986  23.627297  0.019910  0.013100  0.586377  0.000000  0.000279  0.530770  0.004078  0.011636  0.000000  0.000000   0.005445  0.004388  0.005877  0.000400  1.215561  0.021429  0.005590  0.003670  0.000000  0.001588  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.050929  0.015053  0.104453   0.122767  0.000000  0.000000  0.000343   0.000481  1.535667  0.091318  52.880101  0.000933  0.329943  0.0  2.614312   9.232351  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.0  2.868348  0.000000  0.026744  0.000000   0.128611  0.000000  0.049441  0.000000  0.747861   4.649703   0.194667  0.002230  0.000000e+00  0.095171  0.004332    0.429761  8.953811e-05  0.514561  21.753044  3.573798   0.000014  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.086494  0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.008787  0.013936  0.211361  0.000246  4.579582  0.051408  0.034361  3.610196  0.000000   0.176476  7.077663  0.000000  0.103573    0.002899  0.001336   2.437478  0.000000  0.006742   0.000000   
    0122          0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.001704   0.215322   0.000052   0.144528  1.429577  0.000000  1.869959  0.000000  0.000000  0.213683  0.000000  0.092459  0.052490  0.054549   3.761311  0.007157  3.351890  0.004849  4.318209  0.032182  0.001256  0.000000  0.000000  0.000951  0.000006  0.058686  0.000000  0.681542  0.204737  1.946622  13.168414  0.003606  0.000000  0.000000   0.000142  8.679341  1.176507   0.000000  0.649505  1.162449  0.0  0.604442   0.431210  0.000000e+00  0.000000  0.0  0.178929  0.000000  0.069482  0.002235   0.770522  0.000000  1.796879  0.000193  0.003041   1.622033   0.001978  0.000000  7.350485e-07  0.208763  0.000071    0.000000  6.750007e-03  0.014725   0.124527  0.000000   0.000000  0.000426  0.000000   0.058161   0.000042  0.0  0.000000  0.000541  0.000503  0.330381  0.321049  0.000264  0.000000  0.000000  0.859326  0.001074  0.000000   0.020189  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000    0.000342  0.014416   0.076196  0.112682  0.000000   0.015525
```

I want to drop the values that are less than 1

Comment: Drop as in? Set them to 0?

Comment: your question is not very clear, ```df[df.gt(1)]```  this will print you all values greater than 1, and mark ```NaN``` the values less than 1

Comment: if you want to keep the rows where at least one value is greater than 1 then you can do df[df.gt(1).any(axis=1)] but please elaborate a bit more on what exactly you need, with an example of the desired output, so we can give proper answers.